# Using HTML entities in .Net resources

Tags: html, .net, xml, razor

Is there a way to prevent .Net/Razor from escaping HTML entities in .Net resources? We have a web application that needs to be available in several languages. This gives the problem that the texts take up different amounts of space depending on what language they are in. As an example, when a TH element contains "Shipment reference" in English, the browser breaks it into two lines, which is fine. In Danish it says "Forsendelsesreference", which does not get split. We want to fix that by inserting an HTML soft hyphen entity. However, when we do that, it gets escaped, and the page shows "Forsendelses&shy;reference". We can see two ways to avoid that. One is to wrap the content of every label and TH element in @Html.Raw. Another is to identify those labels and headers that use a resource with a soft hyphen, and wrap the content in @Html.Raw. Neither is very appealing. Is there a way to just disable escaping of text from resources in general? It is acceptable to disable escaping of all text that come from @class.property, since we use that only for resources. Anything from the user we get from the model or from Ajax.

Comment: Could you write the soft hyphen as a character and not an HTML entity?

Comment: Thanks. It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Sami Kuhmonen above, you can use actual soft hyphens in stead of HTML entities.

You can just use Unicode soft hyphens. However, those characters are invisible, making your resource file hard to read. You can also use numeric XML character entities in the resource file, linke this: Forsendelses&#173;reference